# Is this allowed in App Store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

I am making an app for some people and they want to instantly update the app whenever they want after first submission. The changes will be like color, fonts, background color, removing a tab from tabbar...
What I was thinking was, creating a plist with entries like color, font and etc for specific views. And everytime an app starts up, it connects to a server and download the plist (if it's updated) and then load it's views according to the plist.

So for example, say the user wants to change the font from Helvetica to Arial. In plist I would have a dictionary with key named "Font" and object is the font name...So I simply update the plist with the font name "Arial" now and next time the app starts up, the font will change.

I hope I made it clear what I am trying to do. Now my question is, is this kind of thing allowed in app store? In reality, I am trying to circumvent the update system of App Store, but just wondering if it's allowed or if someone had experience doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your app  is allowed to do these kinds of things, but be careful that your clients don't get the wrong set of expectations. The review process is not there to stifle creativity and color changes, but to prevent malicious code from running. You're not circumventing anything by using a web server to control the appearance of your app. Consider many apps which take content from the internet. You are merely taking it a step further.

The iTunes App and the App Store app have recently added a "Purchased" view without any user having to download anything new. You should be fine doing the same.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, downloading **content** is ok. Downloading **code** however is not. So if the changes are due to different content you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

While nobody really knows until Apple says yea or nay, there are a few assumptions I believe to be safe:

1) If you're updating executable code (complied binary or a scripting language) you will not be accepted, and if you make it in somehow they'll yank the app and kick you off when they find out.

2) If you're updating resources (content, colors, fonts, etc.) you are probably fine, but Apple may decide to reject you anyway. Have a good case to defend yourself with if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

All those changes are ok with Apple and can be performed dynamically in response to an external trigger (eg. api).
You can do whatever you want as long as you don't attempt to download and run additional code. (if you don't know what his means then you're fine). :)